# vba version 6.5 how to set default member of a class

Tags: excel, vba, class, methods, attributes

I am trying to make a particular method the default member of my class.

From my research the trick is to export the file and add a line like "attribute mymethodname.vb_usermemid=0" to my default member and import it back into my project. I check it in object browser but that member is never marked with a blue dot to indicate it is a default member.

I have read that in the past you could even do it by selecting an advanced button in member properties but with the version I have I do not see any way to do it.

I am able to see default members of other classes that come with MS libraries.  Some of them have a blue dot right beside it so I am sure it could be done.

Working under Vista and Office 2007 VBA version 6.5

Comment: except checking in `object browser` did you try if it isn't default just writing some lines of code and testing? to my experience we can't figure it out from VBE IDE if any class member is default one...

Comment: in fact, I add the attribute line and import it into VBA IDE.  save it and recompile.  THen I remove the class module and export again hoping to see the same attribute line there.  However, everytime I re-export it the line is gone as if VBA IDE ignores it and deletes it.

Comment: Indeed, VBA ignores the attribute in the export process, you should always place the attribute before re-importing your .cls file